# Dynamic data frame transformation using translation table

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm building a few data frames that need to be translated into my own data for my little project.

I have the following attribute table as an example:

```
ID  date        road_tpe    dmg       name
1   11-11-2016  elements              A street
2   11-11-2016  asphalt     B         A street
3   11-11-2016  asphalt     A         B street
4   11-11-2016  concrete    A         C street
```

The result should look like

```
ID  date_of_construction    road_type   damage_asphalt  damage_concrete street_name
1   11-11-2016              03          null            null            01
2   11-11-2016              01          02              null            01
3   11-11-2016              01          01              null            02
4   11-11-2016              02          null            01              03
```

I'm making a standardized excel translation sheet that can easily transform my incoming data into data/ that i want in my own style.

```
category_old    value_old   category_new            sort_of_data    value_new   split_category  split_value

date                        date_of_construction    date            

road_tpe        asphalt     road_type               existing_list   1       
road_tpe        concrete    road_type               existing_list   2       
road_tpe        elements    road_type               existing_list   3       

dmg             A           damage_asphalt          split           1           road_tpe        asphalt
dmg             B           damage_asphalt          split           2           road_tpe        asphalt

dmg             A           damage_concrete         split           1           road_tpe        concrete

name            street_name                         new_list
```

First you get a list of all the category_old unique features to start a loop and check what sort of data it is in Sort_of_data.
According to what data it is you do the following actions.
for date_of_construction this would be:

```
if sort_of_date == date:
 string(category_new[1]) = date ##meaning: date_of_construction takes over the values of date
```

for road_tpe this should be something like:

```
if sort_of_date == existing_list:
    *** make list of unique values based on the category_old and Value_old 
    for i in (length list)
        if value_old of road_tpe == value_old_list[i]
            value_old = value_new
```

`if sort_of_date == split:`
 split that takes road_tpe into account (road_tpe should be stored in a extra attributes split_category and split_value)
 after that its the same as above

`if sort_of_date == new_list:`
    makes a list of all unique values and makes a new table of it that will be exported (name, code, order)
    the code is just a count transformer
    order is the list in alphabetical order
    after this all street names should be replaced by the code.

Is this the correct way to approach this?